# Get total rows hours and minutes

Tags: php, mysql, time

So I get total login hours of a user in the following way. Now I wish to get the total count of all both time_in and time_out datetime fields and display all total hours and minutes.

```
$query = "
  SELECT member_id
       , member_name
       , team
       , time_in
       , time_out
       , SEC_TO_TIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_out) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time_in)) totalhours 
    FROM hours 
   WHERE member_id = 7;
   ";

$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
$rowNo = 1; //Increment Row Number
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$time = $row['totalhours'];

echo "<tr align='left'>";    
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$rowNo++."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$row['member_name']."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .date('Y-M-d - h:i:s a ', strtotime($row['time_in']))."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .date('Y-M-d - h:i:s a ', strtotime($row['time_out']))."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$time." Hrs</font>.</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";          
}
```

Here is an image output

[image: Output of current query]

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: **Stop** using deprecated `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO´

Comment: this is just a offline project i do use pdo now.

Comment: `$rows=mysql_num_rows( $result );` ??

Comment: i need to count the datetime fields total hours and minutes. the fields are time_in and time_out

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code, I hope this helps

```
$query = "select member_id, member_name, team, time_in, time_out, sec_to_time(unix_timestamp(time_out) - unix_timestamp(time_in)) AS totalhours from hours WHERE member_id ='7'";

$result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
$rowNo = 1; //Increment Row Number
$total_time="00:00:00";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
$time = $row['totalhours'];

$secs = strtotime($time)-strtotime("00:00:00");
$total_time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($total_time)+$secs);


echo "<tr align='left'>";    
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$rowNo++."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$row['member_name']."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .date('Y-M-d - h:i:s a ', strtotime($row['time_in']))."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .date('Y-M-d - h:i:s a ', strtotime($row['time_out']))."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$time." Hrs</font>.</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";          
}

echo $total_time;
```

Comment: that was what i was talking about yes it definitely helps. thanks alot mate

Answer (score 0):

There is a function in the PHP mysql_num_rows($result) which will return number of rows return by the mysql_query function.

Comment: but that wont calculate total numbers of hours and minutes from time_in and time_out datetime fields

Answer (score -1):

First you need to change mysql_* to mysqli_* or pdo.

count() is your friend on this.

your query should be like this.

```
select count(*) as total,member_id, member_name, team, time_in, time_out, sec_to_time(unix_timestamp(time_out) - unix_timestamp(time_in)) AS totalhours from hours WHERE member_id ='7'
```

now if you echo `$row['total']` you will get the total count of your records.

> UPDATE

leave your query as it is, and make a $total_rows variable to save the total number of rows.

$total_rows = mysql_num_rows( $result );

```
echo "<tr align='left'>";    
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$rowNo++."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$total_rows."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$row['member_name']."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .date('Y-M-d - h:i:s a ', strtotime($row['time_in']))."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .date('Y-M-d - h:i:s a ', strtotime($row['time_out']))."</font>.</td>";
echo"<td><font color='white'>" .$time." Hrs</font>.</td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: SQL injection has nothing to do with `mysql_*` or `mysqli_*`

Comment: guys this is just offline project i do use pdo :)

Comment: @Rafael not happening mate with that query my one rocord disappears from screem and echoing total i just 2 now total hours and minutes from time_in and time_out

Comment: @jens well 'nothing' is perhaps a little strong

Comment: @Rafael no mate thats not what im talkin about. please take a look at my attached image, there you will see total hours, what i am talking about it get the total by adding hours from both rows